# I cant run it now and I dont know if I should revise my code

Tags: c#, xna

My original was to have a flat land that generated ores below the grass by using a number generator to identify which block was drawn. Now as I have made loops to create that, it won't even start.It puzzles me why and if I should not use do loops than tell me a more efficient way to do this. I have been learning C# for around 2 months and I am trying to get the hang of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace WindowsGame3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D EarthGrass;
        Texture2D EarthDirt;
        Texture2D PooperMachoOre;
        Vector2 BlockPos = new Vector2(0, 300);
        System.Random IDB = new System.Random();

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";



        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);



            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            EarthGrass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/EarthGrass");
            EarthDirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/EarthDirt");
            PooperMachoOre = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Ores/PooperMachoOre");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            int IDBint = IDB.Next(11);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            do
            {

                if (BlockPos.X == 300)

                    do
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(EarthGrass,BlockPos,Color.White);
                        BlockPos.X +=20;                        
                    } while (BlockPos.X < 800) ;
                if (BlockPos.X <= 800)
                    BlockPos.Y += 20;
                do
                {
                    if (IDBint == 10)
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(PooperMachoOre, BlockPos, Color.White);
                        BlockPos.X += 20;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(EarthDirt, BlockPos, Color.White);
                        BlockPos.X += 20;
                    }
                }while (BlockPos.X < 800);
                BlockPos.Y += 20;
            } while (BlockPos.Y > 800);
            BlockPos.X = 0;
            BlockPos.Y = 300;
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, what is your question again?

Comment: Do you know what your code does? It seems like you don't, or you have some very odd reason to try and make *that* work. Currently you just draw some sprites at random locations **determined every draw call**. Not something you'd expect from a real game.

Comment: What is going on in this question? Is this a game you're talking about? Give us less personal information which doesn't seem to matter (like how much time you've spent on this) and more information that is relevant to whatever it is you're trying to ask here.

Comment: I am trying to get this to generate blocks in a line form and use a randomly generated number to decide which block it will draw. When I run this it just says my game stopped working and I have to close it. How should I revise this?

Comment: A `do...while` is not "inefficient" per se but it's not the best choice for what you're doing. Really the only time you want to use a `do...while` loop construct is when you need **at least one iteration** to occur. In your code, you may have at least one occur but you don't **need** it to occur. It's best to stick with a `for` loop for your purpose as you have a fixed number of iterations with a fixed step (which are the requirements that make `for` loops ideal).

Comment: Should I use an array? I could never figure those out.

Comment: @DattManiels If you are not at the point where you can reasonably describe your problem, determine the proper looping constructs or understand arrays then I personally recommend you stop trying to work with XNA for the moment and continue your studies with C#. There are simpler Console games you can write (like Tic-Tac-Toe) that will help you learn structures and looping far better than a (assuming) Minecraft clone.

Comment: I dont know where to learn or where to start I have just been looking up things on the msdn help section and using my general knowledge of python.

Comment: @DattManiels you could try and earn 20 rep points on [gamedev.se] somehow and then be able to join their chat, where you could ask where you should start learning game development. Or just read it without being able to post right now, maybe even use search to find similar questions and go on from there.

Comment: @DattManiels I would also recommend Unity3D over XNA as Microsoft is no longer offering support (updates) for XNA ([source](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-hints-at-replacement-for-xna-for-xbox-one-indie-game-creators#)) and with Unity3D you still code in C# (recommended), or UnityScript (like Javascript) or Boo (like Python). They also opened up the ability to build for many platforms (including mobile) on the community edition. It's a great tool for beginning game development with hundreds of tutorials on Youtube and the greater internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote you in your previous question, you shouldn't use `Random` generators in you `Draw` call, because your sequence of texture will change every frame (60 times per second), and I think you don't want this.

You should declare your random sequence of textures in your `Initialize` method using an array, for example.